# How to load a material file in Unity which is outside Assets folder?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a plane, whose material I want to load dynamically at run time. The said material is outside the Unity Project Folder. How do I load it in my game?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Experiment : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material materialToChange;
    Material m_Material;

    void Start()
    {
        m_Material = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("a"))
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material=materialToChange;
        }
    }
}
```

So here I want materialToChange be a material file whose path I want to give and is outside the Unity Project folder.

Comment: Why can't you keep it inside the project?

Comment: I'll join @gameDev_Unity 's question and add: If you want to be able to afterwards adjust stuff like colors or a texture (image), these you can load from the outside (the image file or e.g. JSON/XML file with colors and settings) .. the `Material` (which is an instance of according Shader) I would not try to load from the outside ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity provides AssetBundles which allow to load assets (GameObjects, Materials etc ... ) at runtime.
The objective is to create an AssetBundle which contains your new materials for example. Then you can download this AssetBundle (from local path or from the web) and extract your assets.
You will be able to change your material with the new one !

Take a look at this page : [Unity AssetBundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Workflow.html)